# Typescript not recognized by SonarQube

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

I have several multi-language projects on my jenkins server. In all of them, Typescript code is analysed with SonarQube. But in one of them not a single Typescript file is analysed, while Javascript files are. So, SonarQube seems not to see the Typescript files at all, the "Lines of code" column of Code-View is empty for them. I looked at the configuration of the project but didn't see any differences at all. So what could be the reason for such a strange behaviour?

SonarQube Version 6.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that typescript was in the dependency-section of package.json file of the checked project. With typescript in the devDependencies-section the problem was solved. However, that is quite strange since according to [SonarQube Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/typescript/) it doesn’t matter in which of the two sections typescript resides.